# Is packed an adjective and in an adverb? "The houses were packed in so tightly without streets."

Tags: verbs, adjectives, adverbs

> The houses were **packed in** so tightly without streets.

Is **packed** an ajective and is **in** an adverb?

How about dropping **in**?

> The houses were **packed** so tightly without streets.

Is packed and adjective or ver-ed?

Comment: Your first sentence does not flow smoothly.  It's a bit clumsy and difficult to understand without a re-read.  When you say, *so tightly without streets*, it sounds causative instead of descriptive.   Were streets removed and now the houses are tightly packed?  I think what you're saying is, *The houses were tightly packed without any streets between them.*  Unless it's somehow required that you use *packed in*, I would drop it.

Comment: It is an exerpt from a lecture on archaeology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In *The houses were packed in so tightly without streets*, "were packed in" is a passive phrasal verb; you could add a by-clause to express the agent of the passive verb. (Although you can use "packed-in" as an adjective.)

In *The houses were packed so tightly without streets*, "packed" is an adjective.

[Packed](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/packed) is sometimes an adjective, as in "The show played to a very packed theatre", and sometimes the past tense/participle of "[to pack](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pack)".

"Packed in" is also past tense and past participle of the phrasal verb [to pack in](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/pack-in); *to pack in* has multiple meanings, one of which is *to fit a lot of something into a limited space or time*.

"The houses were packed in" is a passive construction: active would be something like "Builders packed the houses in".

"The houses were packed" is an adjectival use. Note that "The suitcases were packed (by the men)" is passive with an active form "The men packed the suitcases", but the equivalent doesn't work for the houses.

Comment: If indeed there is a phrasal verb, which I would dispute, it's "packed in" (no "were").

Comment: "The houses were packed in" isn't necessarily passive. It can be adjectival in exactly the same way "packed" can be adjectival. That sentence refers to the *state* of the houses, not *the act of their construction*, so it's adjectival.

Answer (score 3):

*Pack in* is a prepositional verb, and *packed in* is its past participle, used as a predicate adjective. That is, it describes the state of the houses.

[Merriam-Webster *pack in*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pack%20%28someone%20or%20something%29%20in)
1 : to cause (someone or something) to fit into a small space
*We were **packed in** the tiny room like sardines.*

[Collins *pack in*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/pack-in)
2. phrasal verb
If someone packs in things or people, they fit a lot of them into a limited space or time.
*Prisons are having to **pack in** as many inmates as possible.*

[Wiktionary *prepositional verb*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/prepositional_verb)
(linguistics) A two-word phrase, consisting of a verb and a preposition, that has idiomatic meaning.

The following two phrases, *so tightly* and *without streets*, are adverbial. They describe the state further, intensifying it (tightly) and explaining it (without streets).